# Can Tkinter Widget Treeview columns be more customized?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, treeview

Here's the code I've got so far, it's just a lightly edited version of the default code.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("one", width=100)
tree.column("two", width=100)
tree.column("three", width=100)
tree.heading("one", text="Name")
tree.heading("two", text="Date")
tree.heading("three", text="Location")

tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A","1b"))
tree.insert("" , 1,    text="Line 2", values=("1A","1b"))
tree.insert("" , 2,    text="Line 3", values=("1A","1b"))

id2 = tree.insert("", 3, "dir2", text="Dir 2")
tree.insert(id2, "end", "dir 2", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A","2B"))

##alternatively:
tree.insert("", 4, "dir3", text="Dir 3")
tree.insert("dir3", 4, text=" sub dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("", 5, "dir4", text="Dir 4")
tree.insert("dir4", 5, text=" sub dir 4",values=("4Z"," 4Y"))

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

output[image: Just a screenshot of the output]

Can the column directly above "Line1" have the column heading "Name"?

Answer (score 0):

```
tree.heading("#0", text="Name")
tree.column("#0",minwidth=0,width=180, stretch=YES)
```

Not sure what to add, I googled around until I found an example of Treeview that was doing exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24964458)